# Backend Server Scripts

Tags: java, python, database, architecture, alert

I have a system that the backend currently relies on Python.
Basically it has a series of scripts that will go through a MySQL database and check for certain parameters across multiple tables and then perform actions such as send emails and text messages then amend relevant cells to say these issues were dealt with.  There is then another script that sits and listens on a port for UDP packets, unpacks them validates them and if they pass validation inserts them into the database and check to see if the data triggers any alarms will send an email and tech message.
My question is am I doing this the most efficient way? As I am not sure how to have a system of checking to see if the scripts are running and if not relaunch them.  All of them run infinitely 24/7.  Would rewriting them in Java be more stable and efficient?

Comment: If you're worried about them crashing, it is very easy to write a tiny shell script to put in a cronjob to check the status, and if gone, restart it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real way to answer either question without knowing all aspects of the system.

If your system basically have 2 scripts written in Python that perform well I don't see any reason whatsoever to change that architecture.  One more consideration that I would give you to ponder is that at least one of these scripts is a support script and the guys responsible for support mostly don't care much about Java to be able to troubleshoot the code.

As far as JAVA is concerned I am not sure that you would be better off with Java then you are with Python.  There is no shortage of expertise out there in either language but given what the programs are used for I'd say Python would be a better choice.  If you are concerned about performance though I would look at [Cython](http://www.cython.org/) as a possiblity.